# Unity Editor freezes when OnTriggerEnter() plays a sound

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, triggers, freeze, playsound

My Unity Editor Freezes every time the player enters the trigger,

- I have added a keycode to see if the audio source is causing it
- I have commented source.Play()  out of the OnTriggerEnter and used a debug statement to check for collisions working properly

both work without a problem so I know it has something to do with OnTriggerEnter() activating the  source.

```
public class PlaySound : MonoBehaviour
{
    public AudioSource source;
    public Collider coll;
    public AudioClip clip;

    public bool soundPlaying;

    private void Start() 
    {
        source = GetComponent<AudioSource>();
        coll = GetComponent<Collider>();
        soundPlaying = false;
    }

    private void Update() 
    {
        while(source.isPlaying)
        {
            soundPlaying = true;
        }

        if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.Space))
        {
            Debug.Log("Space entered");
            source.Play();
        }
    }

    private void OnTriggerEnter(Collider other) 
    {
        if (other.gameObject.tag == "Player")
        {
            Debug.Log("player entered");
            source.Play();
        }   
    }
    
}
```

One more note, the soundPlaying Bool is for an AI to detect the object as there will be a few scattered around.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nevermind I solved it, the while loop in the update function was likely causing an overflow so I changed it to an if statement and it all works correctly now

Comment: If it is not a bug, you can simply close or delete this post

Comment: It's not an overflow .. is a never ending loop since the exit condition is never changing inside the loop .. your app simply freezes this way .. what you want is e.g. `soundPlaying = source.isPlaying;` ;)